# Impressão diretamente na impressora

Tags: php, impressão, php-7

Tenho um sistema de senhas onde o usuário clica em um botão e é impresso uma senha para ele. Eu precisava que a impressão seja direta, pois usando o `js window.print()` uma caixa de diálogo é aberta. Como resolver isto no PHP 7?

Comment: Se quer que seja impresso para o usuário terá que usar o JavaScript mesmo. PHP roda no servidor, não seria muito interessante imprimir por ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o Woss disse, no PHP você não tem esse controle porque ele não funciona no navegador, só no servidor, então o máximo que poderia fazer é o navegador enviar uma solicitação para o PHP no servidor pedir a impressão e ele mandar para a impressora, portanto a impressora deve estar conectada no servidor ou ser uma impressora disponível em rede.

E isso é até mais interessante. Uma coisa que eu falo sempre, mas quase todo novato (alguns com vários anos de experiência, mas quem não aprende continua sendo novato) ignora é que existem ferramentas certas para cada tarefa. Tem tarefa que não importa muito usar a errada, ou pelo menos o prejuízo não é tão visível (o que é até pior já que a pessoa acha que está bom), e qualquer software que não seja usado esporadicamente por alguém, que não seja para uso externo de pessoas em computadores de fora da organização daquele software jamais deveria rodar em um navegador. Navegadores foram criados para acesso simples e rápido que não exige instalação. Ele traz enormes prejuízos para uso constante, ele não foi criado para substituir o desktop como muitos pensam.

[image: Carro com um cavalo dentro só com a cabeça pra fora da janela]

Eu imagino que as pessoas tentam fazer dessa forma porque não conhecem e não querem conhecer outras tecnologias mais adequadas para a tarefa. Mas isso é gambiarra por definição. A interação com o usuário em navegadores é muito prejudicada, e limitada.

Então mesmo ter um navegador apenas disponível para um usuário pedir uma senha e deixar o PHP imprimir é algo completamente sem sentido, péssima UX e até inseguro.

Ter um servidor web só para lidar com isso e fazer a impressão é como ir do Rio para São Paulo passando por Brasília antes. É muito mais simples fazer isso com outra tecnologia diretamente no computador que irá lidar com a senha, algo que tenha melhor usabilidade e seja mais fácil controlar o acesso.

Se não é capaz de fazer isso peça para outra pessoa fazê-lo. E espero que o resto dos sistemas internos sigam o mesmo caminho.

Se for insistir no erro (e espero que pelo menos tenha a ética de avisar as pessoas que te contratam que isto é um erro) operará como toda aplicação web, já que ela é uma, e use o cliente no navegador só como a interação com o usuário e delegue para o servidor fazer a impressão. Aí o mais comum é usar [`printer_open()`](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.printer-open.php), mas há quem use recursos específicos do sistema operacional do servidor (`print`, `lp`, etc.), ou ainda mandar para um arquivo especial do sistema operacional como `prn`, `lpt1` ou algo assim. Outros usam [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), mas já vi soluções mais exóticas.

Eu respondi, mas lamento por isso, é como dar uma motosserra para uma criança.